# Configure logstash input from DB values

Tags: logstash, kibana, elk, logstash-jdbc

as I am new to the ELK technology i need some help on this. I've a requirement in which i need to get log location(More than 1 for sure)s from a DB table and pass those values in logstash input to view the data in kibana. Can you please share some examples from which I'll refer and go ahead .

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question is very broad to answer here. I would recommend you to get familiar with Logstash https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/index.html 
and then look in inputfilters (jdbc in your case)

Comment: Thanks for the reply I already went through that part already but in my case Its like there is table in database which stores log path location of different servers. I need to get those location from the table first and then I need pass those table data into input section of logstash and show the logs in kibana.

Comment: As @JBone has already stated you should get a pretty good overview of the jdbc input from the documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html). There are multiple configuration examples listed and each setting is well documented. Still, you need to try by your own ;)